Is there something wrong with the java or xml code
This is the java code:
package com.daniel.bmicalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}

and this is the xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_balance"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BMI CALCULATOR" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

It seems like I'm meant to add something to the xml file, but when I added the attribute 'android:id="main"', it still didn't work.I heard that the filename of the xml file could also be an issue, but the name of the xml layout file is activity_main.xml. I'm still a beginner to android programming so I don't understand the reason for this error

Add this to you xml LinearLayout as a property
android:id="@+id/main"

Presumably it's not working, or you wouldn't ask. But how did it fail?

Thank you @cogitoboy. It turns out that was the problem

You need to add the context field in the XML file. Basically, you need to link the XML file with the JAVA file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    tools:context=".activity.java/MainActivity">


There is no need to add tools:context to the XML file. The tools attribute is mostly used by Android Studio's layout editor and Lint to enable various features for layout editing. Have a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolscontext

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
